# Django contstruct object

Tags: django, json, django-models

I'm working on a backend for an app and writing a function to retrieve data from several tables and then construct a httpresponse from that.

What I would like to do is get a vaccine, then all the diseases for that vaccine and then construct something(object, list, dict, ...) containing everything.

What I've got so far is:

```
def vaccinepack(request, country_id):
    vaccines = Vaccine.objects.filter(diseases__countries__id=country_id)
    diseases = []
    json = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    response = HttpResponse()
    for v in vaccines:
        dis = Disease.objects.filter(vaccine=v.id)
        disdata = ""
        for d in dis:
            disdata += json.serialize([d], ensure_ascii=False)
        json.serialize([v, disdata], ensure_ascii=False, stream=response)
    return response
```

But I'm running to trouble when serialising [v, disdata].

```
'list' object has no attribute '_meta'.
```

I'm rather new to Django so I'm not sure what's the proper way of doing this.

Here's my models:

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    diseases = models.ManyToManyField(Disease, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please post your Vaccine model code too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error message is because you're passing a list object to the Django serializer, but it's expecting a QuerySet.

What I would do is to build up the data structure as a series of nested Python dictionaries, and then convert it all to JSON at the end with `json.dumps()`. (Note that's the actual built-in `json` library, which you've shadowed with the serializer.) Something like (untested):

```
serializer = serializers.get_serializer('python')
vaccine_list = serializer.serialize(vaccines)
for i, v in enumerate(vaccines):
    diseases = v.diseases.all()
    disease_list = serializer.serialize(diseases)
    vaccine_list[i]['fields']['diseases'] = disease_list
data = json.dumps(vaccine_list)
```